# Reducing memory alignment

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to know if it is possible to "reduce" the alignment of a datatype in C++. For example, the alignment of `int` is 4; I want to know if it's possible to set the alignment of `int` to 1 or 2. I tried using the `alignas` keyword but it didn't seem to work.

I want to know if this is something not being done by my compiler or the C++ standard doesn't allow this; for either case, I would like to know the reason why it is as such.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can't reduce the size of int but you can go for other stdint types...... int8_t and uint8_t for 8 bit integers, int16_t and uint16_t for integer of length 2 bytes. Unfortunately, not every length is available (3 bytes, 5 bytes, etc are not available)

Comment: The alignment is determined by the platform and is implementation-dependent. You can only request a stricter alignment (i.e. with a greater numerical value) than the implementation-determined alignment. If you want (potentially) misaligned objects you need to implement them yourself.

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu: That is not correct. `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` are native types. The types defined in `<stdint.h>` are of three kinds: The **least** types (e.g. `int_least32_t`) are the smallest native type that is *at least* N bytes large. The **fast** types (e.g. `int_fast32_t`) are types of *at least* N bytes, and might be larger if that larger type can be handled more efficiently by the CPU. The **precise** types you mention, e.g. `int32_t`, are **optional**. On a platform where you **do** have 3/5 byte ints (which would be possible), you won't have `int32_t`...

Comment: true, but on most standard platforms, the precise types are available. your solution also might for him. Let's see what they need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to know if it is possible to "reduce" the alignment of a datatype in C++.*

It is not possible. From [this Draft C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 10.6.2 Alignment specifier      [dcl.align]
>
> …
> <sup>5</sup>     The combined effect of all
> *alignment-specifiers* in a declaration shall not specify an alignment
> that is less strict than the alignment that would be required for the
> entity being declared if all *alignment-specifiers* appertaining to that
> entity were omitted.

The 'reason' for this is that, in most cases, alignment requirements are dictated by the hardware that is being targeted: if a given CPU ***requires*** that an `int` be stored in a 4-byte-aligned address then, if the compiler were allowed to generate code that puts such an `int` in a less strictly aligned memory location, the program would cause a hardware fault, when run. (Note that, on some platforms, the alignment *requirement* for an `int` is only 1 byte, even though access may be *optimized* when more strictly aligned.)

---

Some compilers may offer ways that *appear* to allow alignment reduction; for example, MSVC has the `__declspec(align(#))` extension, which can be applied in a `typedef` statement. However, from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/align-cpp?view=msvc-170): *`__declspec(align(#))` can only increase alignment restrictions*:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
typedef __declspec(align(1)) int MyInt; // No compiler error, but...
int main()
{
    std::cout << alignof(int) << "\n";   // "4"
    std::cout << alignof(MyInt) << "\n"; // "4" ...doesn't reduce the aligment requirement
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm - However, compiling and running the code snippet I gave with the **clang-cl** compiler in Visual Studio 2019 (Targeting Windows x64) gives "1" as the second output. This may be a bug.